# Flutter Image Picker only working in emulator

Tags: image, flutter

Need some help here - relatively new to Flutter. I'm trying to build an image picker that allows the user to select an image from their gallery and once it has been selected is shown in app. It works just as intended in the emulator, but on the two devices I've tested (Android API 26 and 28) the user can open the gallery but once the image is selected, the image isn't saved on the in-app screen. Thereafter the select image button becomes unresponsive. I re-wrote my code in a separate program and found that it works just fine. Possibly something in android build dependencies or permissions?

```
     File _image;
 final picker = ImagePicker();


 Future getImage() async {
   /* Gets the image from gallery or Camera */
   final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery); //gallery
    // final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera); //camera
   setState(() {
     if (pickedFile != null) {
       _image = File(pickedFile.path);
     } else {
       print('No image selected.');
     }
   });
 }
```

```
Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20,),
        color: Colors.grey[800],
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 10),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children:<Widget>[
              Center(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => getImage(),
                  child: (_image == null)
                   ? Container(
                    height: 150,
                    width: 150,
                    child: Icon(
                            MdiIcons.cameraPlus,
                            size: 40
                        ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                      color: Colors.white
                    ),
                  )
                  : Container(
                    height: 180,
                    width: 130,
                    child: Image.file(_image),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20,),
            color: Colors.grey[800],
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 10),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children:<Widget>[
                  Center(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => getImage(),
                      child: (_image == null)
                       ? Container(
                        height: 150,
                        width: 150,
                        child: Icon(
                                MdiIcons.cameraPlus,
                                size: 40
                            ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                          color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      )
                      : Container(
                        height: 180,
                        width: 130,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                image: FileImage(_image)
                              )
                            ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The imagepicker works fine in my app. Try this code and see:

```
class _ProfileImageGetterState extends State<ProfileImageGetter> {
  File _image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
      child: _image == null
          ? GestureDetector(
              onTap: getImage,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        blurRadius: 0.5, color: kGreyColor, spreadRadius: 0.5)
                  ],
                ),
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  child: Image.asset("images/edit-image-pic.png"),
                  backgroundColor: kAccentColor,
                  radius: 50.0,
                ),
              ),
            )
          : GestureDetector(
              onTap: getImage,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(blurRadius: 3, color: kGreyColor, spreadRadius: 1)
                  ],
                ),
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: FileImage(_image),
                  radius: 50.0,
                  child: Image.asset("images/edit-image-pic.png"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```